# How to set ID's name of div with a counter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to define and set multiple div and its ID dynamically like this:

```
function add_div() {
  div_number = 'div' + number.toString();
  document.getElementById("all").innerHTML += "<div  id=div_number > </div>"  ;
  ++number;
}
```

But the name of all the IDs are identical: `div+ number` where `number` is the last value of `number`

By that, I mean, if `number = 20` for 20 calls of `add_div()`

I want to get: `div1` , `div2` , `div3` , ... `div20`

But I get `div20`, `div20` , ... `div20`

Comment: Don't use `innerHTML` for this. And don't number your divs - what is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: Actual problem : I want dynamically define and set ID name  of divs

Comment: No, what's the problem that you think is solved by setting IDs on your divs?

Comment: Use `document.createElement()` and append it, you can also use `setAttribute()` to define attributes to the new/dynamic element and set event listeners.

Comment: I need the name of each ID to close it after clicking on X for example

Comment: *"each ID to close it after clicking"* **It**? if you want one function to apply to multiple elements then I suggest using the `class` name for that.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, verifiable, and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Currently, this code fails to even add `n` divs, and doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Set a counter with an initial value of 1 outside the function, and then increment it each time the function runs.

Comment: I understand, however that's where the problem could lie in *his* code. For example if he has a [delay in the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45472032/how-to-set-ids-name-of-div-with-a-counter-in-javascript#45472107) or some other issue. Plus `<div  id=div_number></div>` isn't concatenating `div_number` so you would get that literal string, not `div20` as OP describes.

Comment: @sideroxylon Or count the existing elements with the same class and add 1...

Comment: Yeah the code you posted doesn't do what you describe. Post the actual JS that outputs your HTML and then we can help.

Comment: Thank you all , I should test all methods !

Answer (score 0):

```js
function add_div(number) {
 for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.id = 'div' + i;
  document.getElementById("all").appendChild(div);
 }
}

add_div(20);
```

```html
<!-- Outputs-->

<div class="all">
 <div class="div1"></div>
 <div class="div2"></div>
 <div class="div3"></div>
 <div class="div4"></div>
 <div class="div5"></div>
 <div class="div6"></div>
 <div class="div7"></div>
 <div class="div8"></div>
 <div class="div9"></div>
 <div class="div10"></div>
 <div class="div11"></div>
 <div class="div12"></div>
 <div class="div13"></div>
 <div class="div14"></div>
 <div class="div15"></div>
 <div class="div16"></div>
 <div class="div17"></div>
 <div class="div18"></div>
 <div class="div19"></div>
 <div class="div20"></div>
</div>
```